# What jobs are available outside airliners in England, and how do I get into them?

Tags: general-aviation, career

I’m currently under training and intend to take on aviation as a lifelong career, but I’ve never taken to the idea of airliners.

What general aviation jobs (like survey, aerobatics, cargo, small charters) are seen to be in demand in England? In my job searches i’ve only really ever come across F/O placements…

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: instructor, test pilot, calibration pilot, skydiver pilot