# Average salary and hours of a survey pilot?

Tags: career

I’m wondering what the average annual pay and hours flown are for a Survey Pilot? Namely in the UK.

Comment: So the next logical question is what does a survey pilot do in the UK?

Comment: @JuanJimenez Well, overflying pipelines for maintenance purposes, aerial photography, wildlife observation, and reconnaissance. I’m sure there are other roles I’m unaware of as it seems to be a very broad industry.

Comment: If this question is related to [this question on aviation careers](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/98570/19), then be advised that many survey missions will in the future be performed by unmanned aircraft. They may still use a pilot for a while, but the pilot will be firmly on the ground. I would not recommend this as a lifelong carreer.

Comment: Thanks @DeltaLima, will take this into account. It seems like a very fun job but I can imagine they will rather have drone operators flying than pilots relatively soon.

Comment: I agree with @DeltaLima, most of this work is already being done using drones, so if this is what you want to do you will have to charge what drones charge. Good luck.